# Invoke BHO function from menu item

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho

Ok, I'm feeling a bit out of water here. It's been a while since I got my hands on C# and I'm all about java so the .NET platform, windows stuff is all greek to me but nevertheless I got this challenge at hand and now I'm faced with a troubling question:

- How do I invoke a BHO function from a menu item in in my tools menu?

I've managed to skip from tutorial to tutorial and implemented a BHO that registers a menu item under 'tools' and I need it to just call one function from my BHO code.

I read that I'm supposed to implement this interface **IOleCommandTarget** but I can't find it, I have no idea what to reference...

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IOleCommandTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

And someone has [done the interop](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/IOleCommandTarget.html) for you.

Comment: Thanks but it is not working... Nothing happens when I click my button and I have no idea how to debug it :(

Comment: Are you sure your dll getting loaded?  In general managed extensions are not officially supported for IE, so I'm not sure how to help you debug.

Comment: It is working now sorry I forgot to update when I accepted the reply :p I still have no clue what the difference was but copy and paste of that interop code made the difference.